# Mapbox GL JS toggle layers using custom controls

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have been playing with different options for toggling layers on and off using the Mapbox GL JS example below. The text buttons that are used in this example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/) work well, but I now need to create custom buttons with icons that can toggle layers for a series of map layers with unique IDs. I've played with some different ideas on how to best achieve this, but haven't gotten far. Is there a way to replace the appended links with icons or some other type of button within the menu? Thanks!

```
var toggleableLayerIds = ['sample-one', "sample-two"];

for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'active';
    link.textContent = id;

    link.onclick = function (e) {
        var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

        if (visibility === 'visible') {
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
            this.className = '';
        } else {
            this.className = 'active';
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
        }
    };

    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating other element before adding on the menu element

see code below:

```
var toggleableLayerIds = ['sample-one', "sample-two"];

for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'active';
    link.textContent = id;

    link.onclick = function (e) {
        var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

        if (visibility === 'visible') {
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
            this.className = '';
        } else {
            this.className = 'active';
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
        }
    };
    var button = document.createElement('div');
    var icon = document.createElement('img');
    icon.src = '[path to your icon]';
    button.appendChild(img);
    button.appendChild(link);
    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(button);
}
```

Here I create a div which contains an image element and the link.
There is lots of possibilities to customize the menu as you want.